# How to create a SQLite database using custom actions in wix, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, wix, custom-action

My application requires a **sqlite database on client side** to store the data from the application.

The sqlite database(eg:Details) should contain a table(eg:Data).
 While I was trying to create the database with a table in

```
D:\tmp
```

folder by using **custom actions** the Database is getting created but it is unable to create the table in it.
While creating the table the installation process is getting **stopped prematurely**.

The code that I have written in the custom action is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace CreateDB
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        private static SQLiteConnection sqlite2;

        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Begin CustomAction1");
            try
            {
                if(!System.IO.File.Exists("D:\\tmp\\Details.sqlite"))
                {
                    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("D:\\tmp\\Details.sqlite");
                    using (sqlite2 = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=D:\\tmp\\Details.sqlite"))
                    {
                        sqlite2.Open();
                        string sql = "CREATE TABLE data (name varchar(20), score int)";
                        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, sqlite2);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one please suggest how to create a sqlite database on client side using custom actions in wix (Visual Studio).

Comment: Why create this database in the setup? You could create it on application launch? Much easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: You can run the above code in your main application.exe on first launch? Instead of running it during the setup? You can't access or write to protected location this way - unless you open ACLs on the target system allowing regular users to write to protected locations. Generally frowned upon security-wise, but it will work if you do it correctly.

Comment: Can you please refer how to run the code in application.exe on its first launch.